# Conditional difference between dates in R using the dplyr function

Tags: r, date, dplyr

Following is a sample of the data set that I am currently working on:

```
C_ID    M_ID    max_ad_date_id  max_DIS_DATE SER_C_DATE_ID   CL_CCT_IND 
102472781   3874931 24/05/2015  28/05/2015   24MAY2015:00:00:00 N
102472781   3874931 24/05/2015  28/05/2015   24MAY2015:00:00:00 N
102472781   3874931 24/05/2015  28/05/2015   25MAY2015:00:00:00 N
102472781   3874931 24/05/2015  28/05/2015  25MAY2015:00:00:00  N
102472781   3874931 24/05/2015  28/05/2015  25MAY2015:00:00:00  N
103011920   3998668 28/01/2015  28/01/2015  28JAN2015:00:00:00  Y
```

I need to create a new dataset where I will have distinct of the first 4 columns & calculate a new variable `LOS` which will be a count of distinct `SER_C_DATE_ID` where `CL_CCT_IND='Y'` else `LOS` is a difference between the `max_ad_date_id` and `max_DIS_DATE`.

I am new to the R environment & tried using the following code to do the same:

```
AllData$max_ad_date_id<- as.Date(AllData$max_ad_date_id,"%d%b%Y")
AllData$max_DIS_DATE<- as.Date(AllData$max_DIS_DATE,"%d%b%Y")

DummyData <-AllData %>%
 group_by(C_ID, M_ID,
    IND) %>%
summarise(max_ad_date=max(max_ad_date_id),
        max_DIS=max(max_DIS_DATE),LOS=n_distinct(SER_C_DATE[CL_CCT_IND=="Y"]
        LOS=(max_ad_date
             -max_ad_date)[CL_CCT_IND=="N"])
```

The code works fine until the difference calculation.

```
 Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
 Column `LOS` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 5
```

I clearly understand that this is a coding error & the difference calculation should probably not be a part of the summarize function. Also tried using mutate function but couldn't use it correctly.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to summarise `LOS` twice, without a comma. Try to use a new line for each variable you want to create within `summarise` in order to spot mistakes easier.

Comment: I can't really reproduce your example (please `dput(head(AllData))` instead of posting the console out), but this _could_ work: `LOS = ifelse(CL_CCT_IND == 'Y', length(unique(SER_C_ID)), max_ad_date_id - max_DIS_DATE))`

Comment: Sorry but the ifelse code gives me the same error as stated above.I did try it earlier as well

Comment: AntoniosK I missed the , while typing in the code on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?